# Which lens will fill the kit lens gap on the Canon 550D/Rebel Ti?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon

I own a Canon 550D, Rebel Ti, can anyone recommend a good general purpose zoom lens to bridge the gap between these following lenses:

- EF-S 10-22mm
- EF 70-200mm F/4 L

I would like to upgrade in due course to full frame camera so would like future compatibilty too. photography is mainly outdoor stuff.

I have in mind EF 17-40mm F/4 L,  or EF 17-105mm F/4 L IS or similar

any pointers would be much appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: There is no EF 17-105 - you mean the 24-105?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bridge the gap and prepare for a future full frame camera I would have aimed for the [EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L USM](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-24-70mm-f-2.8-L-USM-Lens-Review.aspx) or [EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS USM](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-24-105mm-f-4-L-IS-USM-Lens-Review.aspx) - both very good lenses. I think I'd prefer the 24-105 myself.

When you get a full frame camera you might want to look at the [EF 16-35mm f/2.8 L II USM](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/reviews/canon-ef-16-35mm-f-2.8-l-ii-usm-lens-review.aspx) for wide angle, also a very nice lens.

Comment: +1 for this answer. The 24-105 f/4 L IS USM is the perfect "walkabout" or general purpose lens. And as you rightly said, sets you up perfectly for moving up to a full frame sensor like an EOS 5D.

Comment: The 24-105 f/4 is a good walkabout on a full frame but not on the Rebel. However, you already have a wide angle lens so in this case it the 24 - 105 focal length might work well.

Comment: Why isn't the 24-105 good for the croped-sensor cameras? It might be a bit long in the short end, but since he already have a 10-22 that shouldn't be to much of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the **[Canon 17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-17-55mm-f-2.8-IS-USM-Lens-Review.aspx) lens** as it is truly designed for the camera body that you have, and almost perfectly fills the focal length that you are looking to fill in.

It is an excellent lens, and gives **an aperture of f/2.8 that is unmatched in any lens that also offers image stabilization in this range**. This lens is a reason that many photographers hold on to a crop sensor(APS-C) body such as the Canon 7D even when they have full frame available to them.

I know that you suggested you may end up buying a full frame camera soon, and this lens will not be compatible, but I would suggest **buying equipment that suits your needs now, and worry about upgrading when you are ready**. The amount of money that you will lose when you go to sell this lens is comparatively small to the amount of money you will be spending to buy a full frame body anyways.

The Canon EF-S 17-85mm f/4-5.6 IS USM is also a similar lens in this range, but not quite up to the quality or maximum aperture of the lens listed above.

Comment: Note: Sigma and Tamron do make 17-50 f/2.8 lenses as well with "image stabilization" as VC or OS as they call it.

Answer (score 0):

The EF 24-70 f/2.8L USM or EF 24-105 f/4L IS USM are both terrific lenses and will serve you well now and also when you move to full frame.

The EF 17-40 f/4L is also a fantastically reviewed lens and one of Canon's cheapest L series lenses so definitely worth a look at!

Answer (score 0):

To fill the kit lens gap, I'd simply suggest the kit lens: The humble 18-55 IS. It is dirt cheap, actually quite good, and does a better job as a normal zoom than a full-frame wideangle (too short) or normal zoom (too long) would do.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest an alternative.  I love the Canon 17-40 f4L, and while I have tried the 24-105 f4L, it wasn't as capable in low light as I had hoped. Having a low light lens in your bag can not be overstated, as it is extremely useful. For this reason many folks own a 'nifty fifty' 50 f1.8. However, it has limits as well, especially if you can't always zoom with your feet.

You should consider the **Tamron 17-50 f2.8**. It is a fantastic lens, offering sharp low light in an extremely versatile zoom lens.  And having an f2.8 lens in your bag is really a must. While the Canon 28-70 f2.8 is indeed the gold standard, its also a massive piece of glass, as heavy as a gold bar, and not especially wide.  You might also consider the Sigma version of this lens, which gets good reviews as well. I find the Tamron to be surprisingly sharp myself. It is said the non-stabilized version is better than the stabilized (VC) version.

[the digital picture review](http://thedigitalpicture.com/Reviews/Tamron-17-50mm-f-2.8-XR-Di-II-Lens-Review.aspx)

[Fred Miranda review](http://www.fredmiranda.com/reviews/showproduct.php?product=308&sort=7&cat=43&page=1)

[Imaging Resource](http://www.slrgear.com/reviews/showproduct.php/product/1297/cat/23)

http://www.pbase.com/lightrules/zoomzoom (a bit old now)

Comment: I must say that I find the 24-105 IS supremely capable in low light... as long as the subject is quite immobile :) It's why I got rid of the 24-70 and kept the 24-105; IS far outweighed the one additional aperture stop the latter lens gave me. I'd want at least f/2.0 for a low-light, moving-subject lens.

Comment: Indeed, IS helps a lot, unless you are photographing people in a dark church, a situation where I was disappointed in the 24-105 f4L. As you say, mobile subjects can be a pain.

Comment: Sad, but true. I have a 50/1.8 and an (old, pre-loved) 85/1.2 for that kind of situation. The 24-70/2.8 was never enough, unless I added a flash.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I own the the 17-40mm F/4 L (latest acquisition) and the same 70-200mm F/4 L you have. I only took less then a 100 shots with the 17-40mm and am very happy with it so far. It is as they say; a bit short on the long end however and not suitable for close up portraits (unles distorted fetures is the desired effect) but I knew this and bought this lens for a specific purpose. (landscape) I am also not planning on upgrading to a full frame anytime soon although I am not ruling it out in the future if prices drop and budget allows.

I noticed no prime lenses in your list. I have the Canon EF 50mm f/1.4 USM and I find it a perfect compliment to my meager lineup.  In fact when not shooting landscape this lens is by far my favorite lens. Not sure "favorite" is the right word here; most FUN lens is more like it.   Based on my personal experiences, I would highly recommend the **17-40mm f4L and the Canon EF 50mm f/1.4 USM Combo**.

This recommendation of course **depends on the intended use** of your lens(lenses) and whether or not you are planning on upgrading to a full frame in the future.